# What is newest substitute for eventBus?

Tags: android, kotlin, event-bus

I would like to change `eventBus` in my application to another solutions. What is the newest approach for communicating events in different places in app?

Comment: Kotlin Coroutines and Flows do the job pretty good

Comment: How do you use it in that cases? With eventBus I send(post) information in repository class then I receive it with method onEvent and everything works nice. But with flow I;m not sure how to communicate with that case. How to send and receive data with flow if we do not communicate in relation like fragment-viewmodel, but rather the relation is service/repository class -> fragment

Comment: I work with flow and coroutines I also use work manager if you can write some sentences about your relation, communication I will manage how to do it. My idea is that it could be 1. Post event to work manager. 2. Do things with data asynchronously (-> here is a problem) how to receive with flow in fragment to change something on UI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this [link](https://medium.com/@asissuthar/simple-global-event-bus-using-kotlin-sharedflow-and-koin-4b6fa8cb1a37) could help you.